# How to add a specific custom variable in Magento?

Tags: magento, variables

I need to add a custom variable, that receives a specific customer attribute.
Something like below :

```
$prefix = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId())->getPrefix()
```

What would then be able to choose a variable `{{customVar code=prefix}}`

Comment: are u using in html email template

Comment: Follow this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/defining-transactional-variables